# Maven 2 different proxys for different repos

Tags: maven, maven-2

Can I use different proxies for different repositories?  I have 3 repos (nexus, maven central and a private one).  I need to use one proxy for maven central, one for nexus and none for the private one.  I can configure my settings.xml to use a proxy, but only one at a time.

Is this possible, and if not, any ideas on an alternative?

Comment: Why do you need a proxy for a nexus? Ok central i could imaging if you are in a corporate network? But than you should use the nexus ?...Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, I have one proxy for maven central on the Internet.  I have another proxy for a private repo on a corporate network.  I have dependencies for a project in both repos that I need to get to.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I would suggest to configure only the nexus and put the dependencies (private repo? sounds weird) into the Nexus...Apart from the your nexus should already use Maven Central...?